# How to submit form via Ajax using PHP

Tags: php, html, ajax

I'm a complete Ajax newbie.

My non-ajax form currently looks like this:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['D1']) && !empty($_POST['T1'])){
    $providers = array(
        'google_drive' => 'Goole drive^https://drive.google.com/file/d/{replace}/view',
        'clody' => 'Cloudy^https://www.cloudy.ec/embed.php?id={replace}',        
    );

    if(isset($providers[$_POST['D1']])){

        $url =  str_replace('{replace}', $_POST['T1'], $providers[$_POST['D1']]);
        echo "$url";
    }


}
?>

<form method="POST" action=<?php ($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>>

    <p>chose url: 
    <select size="1" name="D1">
        <option value="google_drive">google drive</option>
        <option value="clody">clody</option>
    </select>    
    <input type="text" name="T1" size="40">    
    <input type="submit" value="go" name="B1">
    <input type="reset" value="reset" name="B2">
    </p>
</form>
```

This works fine, except that I want to be able to submit without refreshing the page, so the form info is submitted in the background. I know Ajax is the way to go here and I read lots about it, but I'm having trouble getting it to work. I'm unsure if the Ajax script is supposed to replace the retrieve part or it works in conjunction.

Comment: AJAX is Javascript, not PHP.

Comment: I'm sure there are many tutorials on this topic

Comment: There is zillion's examples over internet on how to use ajax. Just do some research.

Comment: @Barmar  I really do not know the proper way to link them with some
Please Help

Comment: @FelippeDuarte help me please

Answer (score 0):

You can play around with something like this

```
document.getElementById('myform').addEventListener("submit",upload);
function upload()
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST","/upload.php",true);        
    var formdata = new FormData(myform);
    xhr.send(formdata);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
    {
         //some code to check if submission succeeded 
         url = xhr.responseText();
         if(url == 'failed')
              console.log('upload failed'); // do something for failure              
         else
              document.getElementById('urlBox').innerHTML = url; // after creating a div with id urlBox
    }
};
}
```

It's also best if you put `PHP` code in a separate script file.

Say, `upload.php`

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['D1']) && !empty($_POST['T1'])){
    $providers = array(
        'google_drive' => 'Goole drive^https://drive.google.com/file/d/{replace}/view',
        'clody' => 'Cloudy^https://www.cloudy.ec/embed.php?id={replace}',        
    );

    if(isset($providers[$_POST['D1']])){

        $url =  str_replace('{replace}', $_POST['T1'], $providers[$_POST['D1']]);
        echo "$url";
    }
}

else{
   echo "failed";
}
?>
```

And use JavaScript to put the `$url` in `responseText` in its place on the `HTML` page. Modify the relevant areas in the code.

Comment: Please complete the last step responseText

Comment: Forgive me for the inconvenience
Thank you for helping me
But I think there is something wrong
Does not work with me

Comment: @kfane The above piece of code *only* serves as a skeleton. You must certainly go ahead and fill in the details and complete the program.

Comment: @kfane There are several things you are doing wrong. 1. Stop using `XHTML`! Please move on to `HTML5`. 2. It's best you put the custom script tags in the `body` *after* the `form`. 3. There's no need for `action` on your `form` anymore 4. You must create a file called `upload.php`. These are the only few things I can think of. If you could provide more details about the errors you got, I can help further.

Comment: @kfane And of course, you should have a display area (say, a `div`) with an id `urlBox` for it to work.